# How to remove a CSS style on the fly

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I want to add and remove a background style on my CKEditor instance on the fly (with JS so). I have read many examples to add a style, but no solution to remove it.

Here, several solutions to add a style :

```
// solution 1 :
CKEDITOR.instances[0].addContentsCss('body{background-color:black;}');

// solution 2 :
CKEDITOR.addCss('body{background-color:black  !important;}');
```

But these solutions worked on the initialization of CK. I don't find solution to update style after initialization.

Anybody know to do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do so using CKEditor API:

```
editor.editable().setStyle( 'background-color', 'black' );
```

The [`editor.editable()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-editable) method returns the main editable element of the editor.

The [`CKEDITOR.addCss()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss) and [`editor.addContentsCss()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addContentsCss) methods serve different purposes. See the docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I don't use CKEditor object, only Jquery and CSS selector :

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.cke_editable').css('background-color', 'black');
```

Eric